# Excel Cell Style issue

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am using below code to get date value from XLSX file. This is working absolutely fine for some XLSX files, but it is not giving exact date format which is in XLSX file. This issue is for some files.

For example, I have date like this `21/01/2016 (dd/mm/yyyy)`, but after reading, it gives date as `01/21/16(mm/dd/yy)`

Is there any other way to get cellstyle?

Is it issue of XLSX file?

```
String dateFmt = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
                
if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
    double val = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    Date date = DateUtil.getJavaDate(val);

    String dateFmt = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
                                    
    System.out.println("dateFmt "+dateFmt);

    value = new CellDateFormatter(dateFmt).format(date);
                                    
    System.out.println("Date "+value);
                                
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the cell, which is containing the date, is formatted as the default date format (`Short Date`), then only the format id 0xE (14) is stored in the file. See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html. The `*.xlsx` file contains only

`<xf numFmtId="14" ... applyNumberFormat="1"/>`

in `styles.xml`. There is no special `formatCode` saved for this `numFmtId`.

So how this will be displayed in `Excel` depends on the locale settings of the system.

For example with my German Windows system the `numFmtId="14"` will be displayed as `TT.MM.JJJJ` as is set in `Region and Language` settings:

[image]

In English Great Britain Windows systems this will be `DD/MM/YYYY` per default.

But if you change the setting for `Short Date` in the system settings, to `JJJJ-MM-TT` for example, then this format will also displayed in Excel with the `numFmtId="14"`.

So to know how exactly Excel will display the date with the `numFmtId="14"`, one needs to know the exact Windows system settings  in `Region and Language`.

So also apache POI can't know how this should be displayed without knowing the locale settings of the system, since the file contains no infomation about this. So it will assume `en-us` locale. This leads to `m/d/yy` for date.

You could check if the format id 14 is used and if so define your own default date format.

```
   if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
    Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();

    System.out.println(date);

    String dateFmt = "";

    if (cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat() == 14) { //default short date without explicit formatting
     dateFmt = "dd/mm/yyyy"; //default date format for this
    } else { //other data formats with explicit formatting
     dateFmt = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
    }

    System.out.println("dateFmt " + dateFmt);

    String value = new CellDateFormatter(dateFmt).format(date);

    System.out.println("Date " + value);

   }
```

To be clear: This all is only with `numFmtId="14"` `cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat() == 14`. All other date formats will have explicit data format strings `cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString()` and so POI can display them exactly like in Excel.

---

See [POI DataFormatter returns 2 digits year instead of 4 digits year for date cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228302/poi-dataformatter-returns-2-digits-year-instead-of-4-digits-year-for-date-cells/53236531#53236531) for how to use `DataFormatter` to work around this issue.

Comment: @AxelRitcher Thanks for this useful information. I was searching for it, but did not get any explaination.

Comment: @AxelRitcher Your solution worked. Thank you. but one more question. is there any way to get existing format or reading date as it is from excel?

Comment: "Is there any way to get existing format or reading date as it is from excel?" No, not if the date is formatted with `numFmtId="14"` and we do not know the `Region and Language` settings of the Windows system the Excel is running on.

Comment: @AxelRitcher plz check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918775/xlsx-issue-cell-getcellstyle-getdataformat-changing-value-after-adding-or-r]

Comment: @AxelRitcher: I understood completely. but i need to fetch date from excel as it is so i edited my code as per values returned by cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat() for various date types

Comment: All other date formats except 14 will have explicit data format strings `cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString()`. So no need reading `cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat()` for others than 14.

Comment: @AlexRitcher Thank you for complete  answer and information. :)

Comment: @AxelRichter I've got a feeling that there's actually a handful of "localised" formats. You can use [DateFormatConverter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/DateFormatConverter.html) to do the localisation, or force excel into a locale with something like `"[$-0411]dd MMMM, yyyy;@"`

Comment: @Gagravarr can you plz elaborate more on you comment?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Yes there are "localised" formats. But thats another thing. The `numFmtId="14"` is precisely *not* localised but system dependent.

Comment: The DataFormatter() may be created with some Locale however I tried several different locales but date format wasn't changed. Looks like it doesn't work with numFmtId="14"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228302/poi-dataformatter-returns-2-digits-year-instead-of-4-digits-year-for-date-cells/53236531#53236531 for how to use `DataFormatter` to work around this issue.