# i want to get the date as is appearing in excel like : 12/1/2014 in date type cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

Given below is the code i am using to get the date as is appearing in excel like : 12/1/2014. cell type is date type. String dateFmt = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString(); //returning the null

try{

```
    String excelFilePath = "D:\\readExcel\\QA 3715 nigbo PFL F1525W985.xls";       
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFilePath);
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);      
    Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Row row  = firstSheet.getRow(6);       
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            System.out.println(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING + " : "+ cell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            System.out.println(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN+" : " + cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            System.out.println(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC+" :: "+cell.getDateCellValue());// getting Mon Dec 01 00:00:00 IST 2014


            if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){//returning false

                System.out.println("true.... : "+cell.getDateCellValue());

            }

          if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){//returning false
              System.out.println("true.... : "+cell.getDateCellValue());
          }

            double dv = cell.getNumericCellValue();
            Date date = (Date) HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(dv);
            String dateFmt = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
            String strValue = new CellDateFormatter(dateFmt).format(date);// getting null
            System.out.println("strValue : "+strValue);

             DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
            String cellValue = df.formatCellValue(cell);
            System.out.println("cellValue : "+cellValue);

        }       
    } 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't want to apply any date formate externally

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900605/excell-cell-style-issue/34902174#34902174

Comment: thanks for help but it is not useful for me..

Comment: i am getting cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString() is null and workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat(cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat()) is null. I want to get the cell date format and after applying the same i want to get the date value from cell instead of applying my customized date format.

Comment: You haven't read the linked answer in my first comment. At least you have not understand it. If the cell, which is containing the date, is formatted as the default date format (Short Date), then only the format id 0xE (14) is stored in the file. So there is not  a DataFormatString. Only `cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat()` will be 14. How `Excel` will show this date depends on the locale settings of the system, the `Excel` is running on.