# Parsing a date returns d/M/yyyy instead of the expected dd.MM.yyyy format

Tags: java, excel, date, apache-poi

I am unable to parse a German date (`dd.MM.yyyy`) from an excel sheet using Poi. In fact, reading the date cell returns a (`d/M/yyyy`) pattern String date, although the excel cell format is (`Date dd.MM.yyyy`) as it is shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

Source code :

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String dateString = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(11)).trim();//date="1/3/2018"
Date dateStart = dateFormatter.parse(dateString);//throws a java.text.ParseException
```

P.S : A simple solution to circumvent this problem would be using a `SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy")` but I would like to fix this problem and understand the reason behind this unexpected behavior.

Comment: For the default date format (number format id 14) there is not a format string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900605/excell-cell-style-issue/34902174#34902174.

Comment: If you open that same Excel file on a computer with the locale set to US-English, does the date magically (automatically) change to the other format?

Comment: Why using the `SimpleDateFormat` at all? Why not getting the `Date` directly from the cell using `row.getCell(11).getDateCellValue()`?

Comment: @AxelRichter : Your solution is right and without any further complications. Thanks.

Comment: @Gagravarr : I cannot do that given I have only one laptop with german locale.