# POI DataFormatter returns 2 digits year instead of 4 digits year for date cells

Tags: java, apache-poi

Excel cell has date format `m/d/yyyy` and show date with 4 digits year. However POI returns date in another format `m/d/yy`. The cell style returns the same format with 2 digits year `cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString()`.

Is it possible to get the same format as I see in Excel with POI?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900605/excel-cell-style-issue/34902174#34902174

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [Excel Cell Style issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900605/excel-cell-style-issue/34902174#34902174) I have shown that if  a date in Excel which is formatted using the default date format (*Short Date*) only has the format id `0xE` (14)  stored in the file and there is not a format pattern stored anywhere. So how *Short Date* will be displayed in Excel depends on the locale settings of the system.

How working around this issue without using Apache POI's `DataFormatter` is also shown in that answer.

Using Apache POI's `DataFormatter` we can work around this issue with customizing the `DataFormatter`.

Example:

Excel:

[image]

Code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.LocaleUtil;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ExcelDataformatterCustomized {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelExample.xlsx"));

  LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(java.util.Locale.GERMANY);
  //LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(java.util.Locale.US);
  //LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(java.util.Locale.UK);

  DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  if (LocaleUtil.getUserLocale().equals(java.util.Locale.GERMANY)) {
   df.addFormat("m/d/yy", new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));
  } else if (LocaleUtil.getUserLocale().equals(java.util.Locale.US)) {
   df.addFormat("m/d/yy", new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy"));
  } else if (LocaleUtil.getUserLocale().equals(java.util.Locale.UK)) {
   df.addFormat("m/d/yy", new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
  }

  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {

     String value = df.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
     System.out.println(value);

   }
  }
  wb.close();
 }
}
```

Result having `java.util.Locale.GERMANY` set:

```
Short Date
12.08.2018
Formatted Date
Sonntag, August 12, 2018
```

Result having `java.util.Locale.US` set:

```
Short Date
8/12/2018
Formatted Date
Sunday, August 12, 2018
```

Result having `java.util.Locale.UK` set:

```
Short Date
12/08/2018
Formatted Date
Sunday, August 12, 2018
```

Comment: Can you please explain why the pattern inside df.addFormat have single m and d(m/d/yyyy) rather than mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @mnagdev: For [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern `M/d/yyyy` means at least one digit for month, at least one digit for day and four digits for year. So 4/9/2023, but 12/9/2023. Pattern `MM/dd/yyyy` would mean 04/09/2023 and 12/09/2023. For [BuiltinFormats](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html) `m/d/yy` is the built in format for number format code 14, which is short date in Excel.