# How to change formatter using apache-poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, formatter, dateformatter

I try to get data from .xlsx. The format of cell in excel is set: short date. Cell value: 12.01.2018.
In console log I received: 1/12/19 but I need exactly the same value which is in cell. Here is my code:

````
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
String val = formatter.formatCellValue(arkusz1.getRow(i).getCell(j));
tabArray[i][j] = val;
System.out.println("tabArray["+i+"]["+j+"] = " + val);```
````

Comment: why are you formatting value if you need exactly the same value which is in cell?

Comment: I'm new in apache POI. Without this in console is: NullPointerExcepition.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228302/poi-dataformatter-returns-2-digits-year-instead-of-4-digits-year-for-date-cells/53236531#53236531

Comment: You could try with Cell.getStringCellValue() or Cell.getDateCellValue() and then formatting it with java api