# How to get the Raw text from a Date Cell using java POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wsl2.png)

CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(current); // pass the cell which contains the formula

```
                        CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(current);
                        System.out.println("Cell value : "+cellValue.getNumberValue()); // 44319.0
                        cellValue.getStringValue(); // Null
                        
                        
                        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); 
                        String strValue = formatter.formatCellValue(current); 
                        System.out.println("strValue :- "+strValue); // 5/3/21
                        
                         String data0 = String.valueOf(current.getNumericCellValue());
                         System.out.println("data0 :- "+data0); //44319.0
                         
                        String value = formatter.formatCellValue(current, evaluator);
                        System.out.println("value :- "+value); //5/3/21
                        
    System.out.println("Date value :- "+current.getDateCellValue()); // Mon May 03 00:00:00 IST 2021
```

But i need the RAW value as 03/05/2021 as a text.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228302/poi-dataformatter-returns-2-digits-year-instead-of-4-digits-year-for-date-cells/53236531#53236531

Comment: FYI The raw value for a date cell in a Excel XLS file is a number not a string...